# Move Nexus repo to different machine

Tags: migration, repository, nexus

I'm trying to move my repo from a machine to another, and also keep all the configuration and artifacts. Is there way to import these to the new repo without having to do the whole procedure from scratch?

Answer (score 7):

Nexus separates it's runtime files from the home directory containing the software.

Copy the following directory over to the target machine and pretend you're doing an [upgrade](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/upgrading.html).

```
$NEXUS_HOME/../sonatype_work
```